# Create an xy plot with two y axis

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following code. I'm trying to create an xy plot wth two y axis. However I only get one line down the middle. I want y to be the vertical axis to the right and vel to be the vertical axis to the left. I have several sets of data for different positions and I'm trying to place the first at 0.66 on the x-axis, the second at 1 etc but I cannot get it to work. Help please.

Regards,
Jer

```
clc
    clear


%Retrieve data and figure setup
filename = 'G:\Protable Hard Drive\PHD Hard Drive\Experimental Data\Bulkrename Trial\Common data for line graphs\Data for line graphs.xls';
a = xlsread(filename, 'Veldef');
vel = 0:1/37:1;
y = -16/15:1/15:21/15;

%X/D=0.66 TSR5
x = 0.66;
exp = a(1:38,2);
ko = a(1:38,4);
rst = a(1:38,6);

%Plot
h = plot(x,exp,x,ko,x,rst);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XY Plot with two y axis Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648031/xy-plot-with-two-y-axis-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

One option is [`plotyy()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html)

```
x = 1:10;
y = rand(1,10);
plotyy(x, x, x, y)
```

---

A more flexible option is to overlay two (or more) axes and specify what data you want plotted on each.

```
% Sample data
x = 1:10;
y = rand(1,10);

% Create axes & store handles
h.myfig = figure;
h.ax1 = axes('Parent', h.myfig, 'Box', 'off');
h.ax2 = axes('Parent', h.myfig, 'Position', h.ax1.Position, 'Color', 'none', 'YAxisLocation', 'Right');

% Preserve axes formatting
hold(h.ax1, 'on');
hold(h.ax2, 'on');

% Plot data
plot(h.ax1, x, x);
plot(h.ax2, x, y);
```

The `Box` property turns off drawing of the external box around each axis. I'd recommend turning it off for all but one of the axes to eliminate axis tick clutter.

The `Position` property sets the axis size and position to the exact same as the first axis. Note that I've used the dot notation introduced in R2014b, if you have an older version just swap `h.ax1.Position` with `get(h.ax1, 'Position')`.

The `Color` and `YAxisLocation` calls should be self explanatory.

I used `hold` to preserve the axes formatting. If you don't include these and plot your data it will reset the background color and axes locations, requiring you to adjust them back.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Matlab 2016a you can also use new function `yyaxis`. Example from [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yyaxis.html):

```
x = linspace(0,10);
y = sin(3*x);
yyaxis left
plot(x,y)

z = sin(3*x).*exp(0.5*x);
yyaxis right
plot(x,z)
ylim([-150 150])
```

[Resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh7ez.png)