# axis.XTickLabelrotation for plotyy in MATLAB 2014b doesn't work

Tags: matlab, plot

I have MATLAB 2014b installed in my PC the code:

```
h.XTickLabelRotation = 60;
```

Rotation part works but the XTickLabel is hiding and even the 'xlabel'. i have date& time on x-axis and would like to rotate by 60°. Here is the code I wrote:

```
x= {'09.02.2015 12:15:12' '09.02.2015 12:16:12' '09.02.2015 12:17:12'};
x = datenum(x,'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS');
y=[20 35 15];
plotyy(x,y,x,y-10)
datetick('x',31,'keepticks')
h=gca;
h.XTickLabelRotation = 60;
xlabel('Date&Time');
```

It is working fine for plot but doesn't work for plotyy. Is there a trick to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm not really understanding the question. [This is what I get](http://i.imgur.com/mX3Cgcg.png) running the example code. What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry. It's not 'plot' it's 'plotyy'. typo mistake. I have edited.

Comment: Interesting, MATLAB handles the tick label rotation very poorly it seems. The x label is still there but it's cut off by the figure window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was originally just going to point you towards a solution similar to [my answer to a recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634426/create-an-xy-plot-with-two-y-axis/28634655#28634655). But it produces a pretty ugly result, particularly when you resize the figure window:

[image: ew]

I'm not sure what it is about rotating the tick labels that messes up MATLAB's resizing callback, but one workaround is to copy all of the properties from the primary axis rather than just the position:

```
x = {'09.02.2015 12:15:12' '09.02.2015 12:16:12' '09.02.2015 12:17:12'};
x = datenum(x, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS');
y = [20 35 15];

h.myfig = figure;
h.ax1 = axes('Parent', h.myfig, 'Box', 'off');
hold(h.ax1, 'on');

plot(h.ax1, x, y);
datetick(h.ax1, 'x', 31, 'keepticks')
h.ax1.XTickLabelRotation = 60;
xlabel(h.ax1, 'Date&Time');

h.ax2 = copyobj(h.ax1, h.myfig);
cla(h.ax2);
plot(h.ax2, x, y-10);
h.ax2.YLim = h.ax1.YLim;
h.ax2.Color = 'None';
h.ax2.YAxisLocation = 'Right';

linkaxes([h.ax1, h.ax2], 'x'); % Link the 2 x axes for pan/zoom
```

[image: A bit better]

Still some more tweaking to be done but it's much better.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your solution works when one wants to save the figure. But If I have huge data set and If I want to investigate further then it would be completely mess up.

Comment: @nik You need to be more specific. "It would be completely mess up" is so vague it's essentially meaningless. If you're talking about zooming/panning, see [`linkaxes()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html)

Comment: May be I am wrong would you please zoom in and check. If I zoom in only plot2 changes but not plot 1. Would you please check?           linkaxes(gca,'x');

Comment: @nik take another look at the documentation for `linkaxes()`. The syntax you want is `linkaxes([h.ax1, h.ax2], 'x')`