# Matlab: When I zoom in a plotyy graph yTicks don't update automatically

Tags: matlab, plot, zooming, matlab-figure, auto-update

As written above, I want to zoom into a graph that was created with `plotyy`.
When I do this, the `yTicks` don't update to the new limits that are visible.
So it can happen, if you zoom too much, that you don't see any `yTicks`.
I found the `ActionPostCallback` function, but I don't get it work, whilst the `xTicks` are fine.

Code:

```
figure, plotyy(1:10,1:2:20,1:10,1:0.5:5.5)
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: Edited my first post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason plotyy sets the 'Ytickmode' of the axes to manual by default.

As plotyy creates 2 sets of axes for the two datasets setting 'Ytickmode' for each axis should solve this.

This can be done by

```
AX=plotyy(...) %this will create an axis with 2 elements one for each axis
AX(1).YTickMode='auto';
AX(2).YTickMode='auto';
```

Comment: ha, nice one - this is it!

Comment: This solution works best for me since I have subplots in my figure. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to set the `YTickMode` property to `auto`.

```
h = plotyy(1:10,1:2:20,1:10,1:0.5:5.5)
set(h, 'YTickMode','Auto')
```

[image]

Complete code:

```
figure

subplot(121)
h1 = plotyy(1:10,1:2:20,1:10,1:0.5:5.5)
title('Original')

subplot(122)
h2 = plotyy(1:10,1:2:20,1:10,1:0.5:5.5)
title('Zoom')
set(h2, 'YTickMode','Auto')
```

Comment: You will need the first output of `plotyy` to obtain and use the axes handles, `gca` will only modify one of the axes.

Comment: This will only work for one side, but yes this is the underlying problem.

Comment: yep - just seen that! The edit should do it. Thanks.

Comment: `findall` really isn't the best way to do that. What if they have other figures?

Comment: You can always group the handles of interest in a vector - but true, this is not optimal as it is

Comment: Like I said, the first output of `plotyy` gives you that group.

Comment: oops - I did not had a look at the handle of plotyy, edits made. Thanks @excaza !

Answer (score 3):

Because this behavior doesn't seem to be present in a 'normal' `plot` call, this looks like an internal bug with the creation of the axes objects by `plotyy`. As one alternative, you can stack multiple axes on top of each other and therefore utilize the 'default' (for lack of a better word) zoom behavior. This approach also allows you to fully control the behavior of both axes independently and avoid the seemingly many foibles of `plotyy`.

I've slightly adapted [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634426/create-an-xy-plot-with-two-y-axis/28634655#28634655) as an example for this situation.

```
% Sample data
x = 1:10;
y1 = 1:2:20;
y2 = 1:0.5:5.5;

% Create axes & store handles
h.myfig = figure;
h.ax1 = axes('Parent', h.myfig, 'Box', 'off');

if ~verLessThan('MATLAB', '8.4')
    % MATLAB R2014b and newer
    h.ax2 = axes('Parent', h.myfig, 'Position', h.ax1.Position, 'Color', 'none', 'YAxisLocation', 'Right');
else
    % MATLAB 2014a and older
    ax1position = get(h.ax1, 'Position');
    h.ax2 = axes('Parent', h.myfig, 'Position', ax1position, 'Color', 'none', 'YAxisLocation', 'Right');
end

% Preserve axes formatting
hold(h.ax1, 'on');
hold(h.ax2, 'on');

% Plot data
plot(h.ax1, x, y1, 'b');
plot(h.ax2, x, y2, 'g');

linkaxes([h.ax1, h.ax2], 'x');
```

And a sample image:

[image: yay]

Note that I've only linked the `x`, but you can link both `x` and `y` axes with the [`linkaxes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html) call.